# Is multiplication by a scalar an open map in topological groups?

Tags: abelian-groups, topological-groups, rational-numbers, topological-vector-spaces, open-map

If n is any non-zero integer and G is a topological abelian group, under what conditions is the continuous homomorphism $g \mapsto ng$ open or weakly open?

If this map happens to be open for all n and at the same time, G is divisible and torsion-free, therefore admitting a vector space structure over $\mathbb{Q}$, can we affirm that G becomes a topological vector space over the rationals?

Comment: If $G =(\Bbb{Z}/2)^{\Bbb{N}}$ topologised by taking the power of the discrete topology on $\Bbb{Z}/2$, then $g \mapsto 2g$ maps the open set $G$ to a singleton set that is neither open nor closed. So you certainly need some condition. Divisibility sounds like a good departure point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true even for torsion-free divisible groups.  Consider $\mathbb{Q}$ with the topology where $\mathbb{Z}$ is an open subgroup and $\mathbb{Z}$ has the $2$-adic topology.  Then the sequence $(2^k)$ converges to $0$ but $(\frac{1}{n}2^k)$ does not converge to $0$ unless $n$ is a power of $2$, so multiplication by $n$ is not open unless $n$ is a power of $2$.

Moreover, even if $G$ is torsion-free and divisible and multiplication by $n$ is open for all $n$, then $G$ does not have to be a topological vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ (with its usual topology).  For instance, $G$ could be $\mathbb{Q}$ with the discrete topology, and then scalar multiplication is not continuous.  (Of course, scalar multiplication will always be continuous if you give the scalar field the discrete topology, but I assume you wanted the usual topology on $\mathbb{Q}$.)